# Not able to record in Jmeter after OS reinstallation

Tags: java, jmeter

I am using Jmeter 2.13 version and with that I used to record many scripts earlier successfully without any issue . Now, my OS has been reinstalled and I am holding Windows 8.1 , 64 bit version.After re installation, I am not able to record HTTPS web applications even though my proxy configuration is correct. After I setup everything in Jmeter, and click on start from work bench and I navigate to the browser try to access the application, it shows "Server not found" message.

However, the scripts which I saved earlier are working fine without any issues. only the new recording is not working.

Help me with the possible solutions.

Answer (score 1):

"Server not found" indicates that browser is unable to access Internet (or intranet).

Most likely you're sitting behind the corporate proxy server and in previous JMeter installation you had these proxy server details specified in *system.properties* file like:

```
http.proxyHost=10.20.30.40
http.proxyPort=3128
https.proxyHost=10.20.30.40
https.proxyPort=3128
```

Double check with your network administrator if this is the case, if yes - take steps from Using [JMeter behind a proxy](http://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/get-started.html#proxy_server) User Manual chapter.

You can also try out [JMeter Chrome Extension](https://guide.blazemeter.com/hc/en-us/articles/206732579-Chrome-Extension) as an alternative solution - in that case you don't have to worry about proxies and SSL certificates substitution.

Comment: Thanks for your response. It some how started working in chrome and IE but on Mozilla still getting server not found error. Will check the System. properties file